# What do you call the power of a unit of measure?

Tags: terminology, dimensional-analysis, units

Regarding units of measurement, it's possible to have powers (e.g. the meter, the square meter, the cubic meter). Is this called the “power” of the unit? Order? Dimension ("dimension" is potentially ambiguous)?

Update: My need for a name stems from writing code to do unit-based calculations. I have to store the power of a unit in a variable, and don't know what to call that variable.

Comment: What do you mean is it possible? Of course it is possible...square meter is what you get when you multply to lengths given in meters, say, two sides of a..square :) Meaning of square meter is: Amount or size of a surface equivalent to size of a surface that has a shape of a square with sides of one meter. Same goes for cubed units but now we are talking about volume. Also, you can have square time units, eg. square seconds. You can have a unit that is W (Watt) multiplied by h (hour) which is called watt-hour and is actually unit of energy. many things are possible.

Comment: That's just to set up the question. I'm not asking if it's possible. I'm asking what you call it.

Comment: But you did ask if it is possible...Regardles, do you want to know how do you call such units that are actually made from basic units? I guess you could call such units compound units in general.

Comment: I’ve never had reason to talk about this number, but if I did I’d call it the “exponent” of the unit.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. Or even "whatever". The name of the variable in the code has no consequence

Comment: What you called it in your question, the power of the unit, is probably the best term.  I don't know of any other term.  This is not really a property that needs to have a name in typical scientific usage

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly say that e.g. $\mathrm{m}^3$  is a power of the unit metre, but the power of a unit is itself a unit, and any product of power of units is a unit, and there’s no need of a special name for this. Therefore, $\mathrm{m}^3$, $\mathrm{V}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$, etc. are all units.

The dimension is a different thing: it expresses the dependence of a quantity on the base quantities in a system of quantities.

Comment: My need for a name stems from writing code to do unit-based calculations. I have to store the power of a unit in a variable, and don't know what to call that variable.

Comment: @Rick Then there is something wrong in the structure of your code, because, as I said, the power of a unit is a unit, and so it shouldn’t be stored in a different kind of variable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but more of a "frame challenge."

If you are coding up logic to handle units, one way to handle this that avoids needing to store the power of a unit, is to define a "Unit" class. Then you have base units that inherit from the Unit class, like "Meter," "Second," and "Kilogram." Finally, you define multiplication and division operations for each Unit class, which return a new Unit object, so that it's possible to combine base units to form compound units. Then in the code "meters-cubed" is technically a different unit than "meters", which mimics how I think about it in physics.

This is essentially how [astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/index.html) deals with units. For example, see the `__mul__` function under the [UnitBase](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/units/core.html#UnitBase) class.